# HashSet.clear() not working as expected

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I have a hashmap which has a hashset of strings as values. I worked out a test code - shown below :

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> hmap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("a");
    set.add("b");
    set.add("c");
    set.add("d");

    hmap.put("a", set);

    set.clear();// = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("a");
    set.add("b");

    hmap.put("c", set);

    set.clear();// = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("a");
    set.add("b");
    set.add("c");

    hmap.put("b", set);

    for (Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : hmap.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
    }
  }
```

I am reusing the same hashset to populate the values in the hashmap. But I see that hashset.clear() is not clearing the values as expected.

The code I get for the above code is -

```
b - [b, c, a]
c - [b, c, a]
a - [b, c, a]
```

So, the all the values are overwritten by the last HashSet. I read javadoc for clear() and the expected behavior is that the elements of the hashset are removed on calling clear.

Output when I use new HashSet instead of hashset.clear()

```
b - [b, c, a]
c - [b, a]
a - [d, b, c, a]
```

This is the output I am expecting.

The reason I do not want to use `set = new HashSet<String>` each time is because I do not want create too many hashsets ( the size of hashmap is expected to be large). Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're using the **same** set so what you'll get is only the most recent values after the last "clear"

Comment: Every value of your map is the *same set object*.

Comment: "The reason I do not want to use set = new HashSet<String> each time is because I do not want create too many hashsets" - but you *need* multiple hashsets. One isn't enough!

Comment: The three elements in map are referencing the same instance of set. When you print them, they read its last status (the content for b). All the things you do before are of no use.

Comment: Well-written questions are often a rarity nowadays :)  Yours has a test-case, what you got, and what you expected, so can't ask for much more!

Comment: @Oliver If only it were a Junit test ;)

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. So , is there anyway apart from creating a new hashset every time? I guess, not?

Comment: If you move the `hmap.put` line *above* the corresponding `set.add` lines, you'll see the map will still show the set containing the elements that were added afterwards. That should help to demonstrate what is happening. If you only call `new HashSet` once, there is only one `HashSet` object in memory.

Comment: @maddie : 2 tips for the future — 1) Use the [Java diamond operator](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+diamond+operator) to simplify generics... this `HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> hmap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();` becomes this `HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> hmap = new HashMap<>();` the compiler can figure out the types needed on the right-hand side. 2) Use _interfaces_ in declarations, classes when creating instances: `Map<String, Set<String>> hmap = new HashMap<>();` / `Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: @Stephen P Thanks for the suggestions, I will keep those in mind while coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the address of the HashMap or Debuging it, you can see that all Objects are refering the same address.

If you are using the eclipse or netbeans, you can make a breakpoint and see the address and status of each step.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you are modifying the same `set` object i.e., all of your 3 keys (inside the `Map`) hold the reference to the same `set` object.

So, if you want to clear and work on the each `set` independently, just use the new `set` object for each key inside the `Map`:

```
set = new HashSet<String>();
```